# Python - Slowly type each character

Tags: python, character, delay

I'm trying to print multiple characters on one line with a delay between each, in Python. I'm using v3.5.

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
import time

for i in range(30):
    print("-",end='')
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Looking at it, I would expect "-" to be printed 30 times, with .5 second delay between each "-". This would all be on one line. When I tried this, the program would seemingly "freeze" by doing nothing for 15 or so seconds. During this time, I'm sure the program is going through this loop, but the "-"s are all printed **simultaneously** after the time is up.

This is because of end=' ', correct? Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: I think this may be due to your terminal's character buffer, as it works fine for me on CPython, in IDLE and GNOME Terminal.

Comment: I use this in a few scripts, actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `flush=True` so the output is not buffered:

```
import time

for i in range(30):
    print("-",end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it uses a builtin, not `sys`.

Comment: @cat, yes, one of the many  advantages of print being a function in python 3, you can achieve the same in python 2 if you `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: I went crazy for a second trying help(print) and getting errors. Then I realized that my default Python was still 2.7. You can put parentheses around your print statements in Python2, but you need Python3 for the cool stuff.

Comment: @nortally, yep, function vs a statement. You can still do the cool stuff in python2 if you import from future

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, You can, but apparently flush is a post-__future__ feature.

Answer (score 1):

There's (line) buffering for the output, add `sys.stdout.flush()` to your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of buffering: the system doesn't print things until it gets a newline or the buffer fills up.  I don't have v3 here, but I think that inserting a **flush** operation should fix the problem.

```
import time, sys

for i in range(30):
    print("-", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: This will fix the problem, but what's more interesting is the fact it occurs at all.

Answer (score 0):

I effortlessly reproduced the behavior with ipython3 in Gnome Terminal. Then I looked at help(print) and added a parameter to the print command. Guess which one?

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

```
Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

Comment: Clearly I've lost the race to post this answer ;-)